# Call button.click() from javascript does not perform the validation property on the button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:PerformPurValidation();" id="PurClick" class="CreatePur"> &nbsp; Create Deal &nbsp;</a>     

<asp:Button ID="ActualPurCreateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Visible="false" OnClick="ActualPurCreateButton_Click"></asp:Button>
```

jscript

```
function PerformPurValidation() {  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ActualPurCreateButton').click();
        });
}
```

I have created a custom button which would submit the form with the html a tag.

This must call the asp:Button click. When I click the actual button, the validation is performed and the requiredfieldvalidators work correctly. But if I call the button by clicking the custom button and having the click called via jscript, the validator doesn't work any more, is there anyway to achieve what I wish to have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PerformPurValidation() {  
        $(document).ready(function () {

  var button = document.getElementById('<%= ActualPurCreateButton.ClientID %>');

          button.click();
        });
}  

    </script>
```

aspx code:

```
     <a href="javascript:PerformPurValidation();" id="PurClick" 
class="CreatePur"> &nbsp; Create Deal &nbsp;</a>     

            <asp:Button ID="ActualPurCreateButton" runat="server" 
   style="display:none"
                OnClick="ActualPurCreateButton_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Only thing I had to do slightly differently to your code is just put the asp:Button in a div with style=Display:none;" as the style att is not available for asp:Button.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Page_ClientValidate(). I've had simmilar problem. Example:

```
function performCheck() {
        Page_ClientValidate();
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            //alert('it is valid');
            return ShowProgress();
        }
        else {
            //alert('No valid');
            return false;
        }
    }
```